# Passing JavaScript function from parent.jsp to showModalDialog without creating .js file

Tags: javascript, jsp

Here I have a js function() in parent.jsp. From parent.jsp I'm redirecting the page to showModalDialog for validation purpose. I want the function() to be called in showModalDialog and the validated values should get returned back to parent.jsp. Without creating the .js file. Is this possible?

If you cant understand my question, please have alook at the flow

```
one.jsp
<script>
function1()
{
  ...
}
url=two.jsp
</script>
```

After redirecting to page two

```
showModalDialog
function2()
{
  function1()
}
```

I passed the values from parent.jsp to showModalDialog by assigning

`Url ="../jsp/validateshowModalDialog.do="&varCurrentValue="+varCurrentValue+"&varCurrentRow="+varCurrentRow;`

And also I would like to pass the function() to showModalDialog  *Without creating the .js file

Comment: You don't pass functions. If the JS isn't loaded on the page you can't call it--either duplicate the function or create a JS file.

Comment: @DaveNewton . Sorry, I forgot to mention that, I'm using window.open to do the validations in the showModalDialog. Isn't it possible in this? Because Im passing the values from one.jsp to showModalDialog for some calculation purpose and I'm getting back the calculated values back to one.jsp, then why not the functions can be called in showModalDialog!

Answer (score 0):

1)define document.ready function in one.js and while directing back
 2)From two.js pass the relevant parameters In the document.ready of one.js
 3)Based on whatever you got from two.js after validation call the function of one.js
and perform remaining processing

Answer (score 0):

Function from parent.jsp

```
Parent.jsp

function parnt()
{
 .....
}
```

in showModalDialog
calling function from parent

```
function child()
{
       if(window.dialogArguments) //for IE          
       {
             dialogArguments.parnt();
        }
        else if(window.opener) //for other Browsers
        {
            window.opener.parnt();
        }
}
```